# How do I earn new cards in Mortal Kombat X?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x-mobile

I just downloaded Mortal Kombat X on my android and have been playing it for a couple hours. Checked youtube for gameplays too. But I need to ask some questions regarding this game.

What I have not been able to grasp until now is that how do I earn new cards. I was given 3 cards namely Lin, Osh and Shirai and got Sonya Blade as some offer that is going these days. I have completed one tower in battle mode and one fight in Faction wars too. How can I get those cool ass cards is what I want to know?

Also there are 4 tiers like gold, silver bronze and more like light silver. What do they mean? Is card of one tier stronger than the other card? Also sometimes when I win a match I see those fatalities (slow killer moves) especially if I invoke an ally or with Shirai but at the end of match if its sonya or osh, why is there no fatalities or do I have to press some special button to see them?

I have under stood the stats written on a card but what is the meaning on symbols on card those small circles with drawings in them. Is it like class of a card as sonya has shooter class and thus pointing gun symbol. If that is the case, which class is better against which class, is there a chart like DH 5?

Answer (score 1):

In Mortal Kombat X there are quite a few ways to unlock new cards. The first and easiest way to get new cards are to buy card packs from the store which will give you a random card of the rarity you selected. Also note that there are three rarities of cards that you can obtain, Bronze, Silver, and Gold and they increase in power as you go from Bronze to Silver then Gold with Gold being the strongest cards you can get. There are cards you can buy in the store that aren't in packs but I would recommend not buying these as they cost a lot more than the random card packs.

The second more difficult way to get cards is to participate in events, in Mortal Kombat X there are events hosted every month or so where you can obtain rare event cards that are unique to the event and won't be purchasable in the store after the event. These are usually long strings of battles with some sort of gimmick imposed on you, such as bronze only cards or what not.

The third way of getting cards is through the "story mode" after you complete certain towers you may receive a card when you complete the tower. However they usually give you bronze cards that are honestly not that great so I would mostly focus on buying card packs and getting your ranks boosted with higher tier cards faster.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those cards are better. I would say make your bronze cards really good and then play some online tournaments where you get rewarded every week if you play you get those green coins for participation. The rewards are higher based on how high you get. I would recommend doing the events even if it's only the first tier. If you complete that, you just earned yourself 30.000 gold coins to buy a silver pack and get a great or less great silver character then just save your green coins (souls) up to 150 and buy a Kombat Pack.

You always get a gold character witch the chance of an exclusive like spec ops scorpion.

Those awesome x-ray attacks you saw are only for gold and diamond (what you call light silver) and those logos it isn't that the one is better than the other, it's just an indicator to make the characters separate from each other.